# why is my footer is being cut off when resizing the browser and side scrolling?

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a footer on a webpage that has another div with some content in it (that content is centered withing the footer container).  The footer is set to stretch the entire width, while the content div inside is set to 960px and has a margin auto to center it.:
Html:

```
<footer> 
  <div class="footer-inner">Content</div>
</footer>
```

css:

```
footer {float: left; min-width: 100%; background-color: #000;}

footer-inner {width: 960px; margin: 0px auto;}
```

The footer does span when full size, but when I resize the browser and side scroll it no longer stretches across full width, but gets cut off:

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/1r2T2h3K3Z1A/o

site: http://southland.dcsam.com

Any help is appreciated. I'm searched and read and searched and read, and now defer to you fine folk. ;)

Comment: Authentication is required to access your site.

Comment: Your domain is restricted I need to check it on firefox but it required authentication.

Comment: Hey Ali, I tried that... with no sucess.  Are you guys still unable to access? I've disabled authentication and you shouldn't be blocked...

Comment: @jive; check my answer and let me know if that one works.

Comment: Still Need authentication

Comment: why is your footer floated left if it's min-width is 100%;?

Comment: Remove the float. Shouldn't be needed. Although we can't tell for sure since it's locked...

Comment: hey Pete, I tried following this when I searched for help: www.cssgirl.com/resources/2012/01/15/100-full-width-header-and-footer-with-centered-content-revisited-again

Comment: Guys -smacks forehead- I posted the wrong url.... the url is http://southland.dcsam.com  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Something is causing your page to stretch to a minimum of 1160px (I'm not sure exactly what it is and don't have time to figure it out, but my best guess is that it's somewhere in your nav or slider). So with a width or min-width of 100%, it only stretches across the window (the same is true of your other 100% color bars like nav). When the window is less than 1160px, your footer will also be less than 1160px. If you change your css to what I have below, it will always stretch the full width of the site:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1160px;
}
```